# Rotation of a function about the y-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I was revising my notes and I came across a question, particularly question 5 as seen below.

The working out says to take the volume of the cylinder away from the volume of the hole.

But shouldn't we just find the volume of the hole since that is technically solid when we rotate x = root y around the y axis?

My understanding is that we would only carry out the method in the working out below if we needed to find the volume of the solid portion of a bowl. But this is not what the question is asking. Am I correct?

[image]

Comment: Your integral $\int_{0}^{1} \pi(\sqrt{y})^2~dy$ calculates the volume of the region bounded by the lines $y = 0$, $y = 1$, the $y$-axis, and the curve $x = \sqrt{y}$, that is, the volume of the hole.

Comment: So for this question, I could have just stopped at the part where I found the volume of the hole?

Comment: No, you wanted to find the volume of the bowl, so you had to subtract the volume of the hole from the volume of the cylinder.

Comment: The question never asked for the bowl though. The initial question just asked for the solid formed by rotating the region bound by y = x^2 around the y axis. Wouldn't this just mean that we want the volume of the hole?

Comment: My apologies as I realised I was not explicit in mentioning what the question asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second problem, you are asked for the volume when the region bounded by the curve $y = x^2$, the $x$-axis, and the lines $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ is rotated around the $y$-axis.  That region is shown below.

[image: region_bounded_by_coordinate_axes,_the_line_x=1,and_the_curve_y=x^2]

Your instructor observed that the volume when this region is rotated around the $y$-axis is equal to the volume when the region bounded by the curve $y = x^2$, the line $y = 1$, and the $y$-axis is subtracted from the volume of the cylinder formed by rotating the region bounded by the coordinate axes and the lines $x = 1$ and $y = 1$.  The cylinder has radius $1$ and height $1$, so its volume is
$$V_{\text{cylinder}} = \pi r^2h = \pi (1)(1) = \pi$$
The region bounded by the curve $y = x^2$, the line $y = 1$, and the $y$-axis is shown below.

[image: region_bounded_bythe_curve_y=x^2,_the_y-axis,_and_the_line_y=1]

Since you are integrating with respect to $y$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $y = x^2 \implies x = \sqrt{y}$.  When $x = 0$, $y = 0$; when $x = 1$, $y = 1$.

Using the [disc method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration), the volume to be subtracted is
\begin{align*}
V_{\text{hole}} & = \int_{0}^{1} \pi \sqrt{y}^2~dy\\
                & = \int_{0}^{1} \pi y~dy\\
                & = \pi\frac{y^2}{2}\bigg\vert_{0}^{1}\\
                & = \frac{\pi}{2} - 0\\
                & = \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$V = V_{\text{cylinder}} - V_{\text{hole}} = \pi - \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: I’m so silly. I completely missed that. Thank you so much.